# JQuery Mobile Select not formating properly from asp.net web form

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I am creating a simple mobile app using an asp.net web form that I would like to use the JQuery mobile Select Menu control in. The problem I am having is that the control does not render properly when I test the app. I am using the demo on W3 Schools for comparison,[1](https://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_form_select.asp). I pull the content of the select using a data reader. page code for this section is as follows.

```
                    <fieldset class="ui-field-contain">
    <label>Channel</label>
        <select name="Channel" id="channel">
            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqlChannel">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
          </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
                <option value='<%# Eval("LocationName") %>'>
                    <%# Eval("LocationName") %>
                </option>
    </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater> 
    </select>
        </fieldset>
```

When tested this renders as:

```
   <fieldset class="ui-field-contain">
    <label>Channel</label>
        <select name="Channel" id="channel">
                <option value='CG'>
                    CG
                </option>
                <option value='KS'>
                    KS
                </option>
                <option value='KT'>
                    KT
                </option>
                <option value='LOST'>
                    LOST
                </option>
                <option value='PART'>
                    PART
                </option>
                <option value='UNL'>
                    UNL
                </option>
    </select>
        </fieldset>
```

My understanding from looking at the W3Schools example is that JQuery is supposed to insert a button and div into the page so that I get the button select.

It does not look like JQuery mobile is firing on page render on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the noise on this forum. This issue was caused by not having all the JQuery libraries loaded.